# How can I bend bottom section of a rectangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

If possible I would like to draw following figure:

[image]

I can draw normal circle or rectangle but I was not able to bend bottom section of it.

---

My code that is able to draw a basic rectangle:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rectangle,minimum width=10mm,minimum height=10mm,draw] at (0:0) (A) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here I was not able to erase bottom section of the rectangle and re-draw as a newly cut version.

Comment: Try `type` shape of `shapes.symbols` Ti*k*Z library. Package documentation,  page 807.